# iPad storyboard not working with SplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm creating an iOs app that fetches pictures from flickr.
I was modifying my project to have it working in both iPhone and iPad, but my iPad storyboard isn't working: it simply doesn't show the picture in the detail view of the SplitViewController, and in the master view of the controller, the row of the tableview looks like it's selected.
I followed a very similar code, and I also took at look at the storyboard, and I think I have it right, but it really doesn't work.

I took a screenshot, but in case you wanna take a look at the whole storyboard or code, it's in https://github.com/noloman/StanfordFlickrFetcher

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you connected the segue to the controller itself (PhotosTVC) rather than the cell.